# Hooke's Law Problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, potential-energy, spring

This question assumes that the spring obeys Hooke's law.

Say we have a spring Length $L$.

The energy of said spring when extended will be $E=(kx^2)/2$.

The extension $x_1$ of said string would be $x_1= \sqrt{\frac{2E}{k}}$.

The extension of half the spring, i.e. the extension of $L/2$, would be x1/2,

$=((2E/k)^\left(0.5\right))/2$

$=(E/2k)^\left(0.5\right)$

Say we have another identical spring, but of length $L/2$.

The energy of 2 such springs would be $E= kx^2$.

The energy of one such spring would be $E/k= x^2 $

Hence the extension $x_2$ of the spring $L/2$ would be $x_2=(E/k)^\left(0.5\right)$

x1/2 =/= $x_2$, despite the lengths being half of each other's.

After looking at this for a while, I thought that it is possible that the spring of lengths $L$ and $L/2$ have different values for $k$. However, if the two springs are identical in material, etc. then how can they be different?

Comment: IMO this question is about a concept and should not be closed under the homework policy. The last line clearly states this: "if two springs are identical in material how can their k be different" (I paraphrase). Seems legit to me.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, they are different.  $k$ is not a property of the material, its a property of the entire object.

Imagine having a small amount of a fairly tight spring.  It takes a lot of effort to extend it even a centimeter or two.  Now without changing the material, connect a few hundred of the springs together.  Extending it a centimeter now will take much less effort.

In fact, springs connected together into a new spring have an equivalent spring constant such that the reciprocal of it is the sum of the reciprocals of the individual springs.

$$\frac{1}{k_{equiv}} = \frac{1}{k_1} + \frac{1}{k_2}+ ...$$

See also the wikipedia article on [connected springs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_springs).

Comment: The same logic of resitors.